# Euler's Number including a negative exponent as best-fit line Function for a Gnuplot Graph

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I'm trying to Plot a best-line fit through several points with gnuplot. There are three data packages which should be all in one plot, including a best-line fit for each package. This is my code so far:`

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

#Output Settings

set terminal pdfcairo
set output "Graph_Versuch_2.pdf"

#Graph Settings

set title "Abnahme der Umdrehungsfrequenz"


set xlabel "Zeit in Sekunden"
set xrange [0:60]

set ylabel "Drehzahl in RPM"
set logscale y

#Fit Settings

z(x) = j*exp(p*x)
k(x) = i*exp(o*x)
n(x) = m*exp(v*x)

#Plot Settings

fit z(x) "Werte_1.txt" via p,j
fit k(x) "Werte_2.txt" via i,o
fit n(x) "Werte_3.txt" via m,v

plot "Werte_1.txt" u 1:2 title "Messreihe 1" with points lc rgb 'red' pt 7
ps 0.25, "Werte_2.txt" u 1:2 title "Messreihe 2" with points lc rgb  
'green' pt 5 ps 0.25, "Werte_3.txt" u 1:2 title "Messreihe 3" with points
lc rgb 'blue' pt 9 ps 0.25, z(x) with lines lc 'black', k(x) with lines, 
n(x) with lines
```

But now there are two Problems: The first one is that as soon as I put a minus inside the brackets of the Euler's number there is no Diagramm (I don't know why) and the second one is the fact that if I use a positive exponent in the Eulers number there is just one best-fit line.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain why these Problems occure and how to fix them.

The data Packages:

```
0       498.4
5       478.6
10      461.9
15      446.6
20      427.1
25      410.1
30      394.1
35      381.1
40      367.4
45      351.5
50      341.5
55      316.4
60      157.4

0       448.8
5       429.7
10      415.6
15      397.8
20      382.4
25      369.0
30      354.7
35      342.1
40      329.9
45      316.1
50      305.7
55      292.8
60      281.7
0       498.6

5       478.8
10      461.2
15      444.0
20      428.2
25      412-8
30      397.9
35      382.6
40      368.8
45      354.9
50      340.8
60      315.9
```

That's the part I included:

```
#Fit Settings

z(x) = j*exp(p*x)
k(x) = i*exp(o*x)
n(x) = m*exp(v*x)

#Plot Settings

j = 500
i = 500
m = 500
p = -1
o = -1
v = -1

fit z(x) "Werte_1.txt" via p,j
fit k(x) "Werte_2.txt" via i,o
fit n(x) "Werte_3.txt" via m,v
```

And that's the error I get:

```
Iteration 0
WSSR        : 1.78982e+06       delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : 0
delta(WSSR) : 0                 limit for stopping : 1e-05
lambda    : 3.30143

initial set of free parameter values

p               = -1
j               = 500
         Undefined value during function evaluation
"Plot_1.txt", line 34:
```

Comment: not sure if that impacts the outcome, but in "fit z(x)" the fit parameters are reversed, i.e. you type via p,j instead of via j,p

Comment: I tried it, but sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to help gnuplot by specifying some reasonable initial conditions for your fitting parameters, see `help fit starting_values`. For example, adding

```
j = 500.
i = 500.
m = 500.
p = -1.
o = -1.
v = -1.
```

before your `fit` commands gives something reasonable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Never Thought of this idea but it seems to work great. But it also seems that I'm still doing something terribly wrong. I tried it the way you suggested but than I got an error saying "Undefined value during function evaluation". I googled the error but it seems I don't understand it the right way because I can't fix it.

Comment: That's odd; it works fine here. Could edit your post to include the output you get when you run the script (especially the diagnostics printed by the `fit` commands)?

Comment: I tried to fix it on a Mac OS and it worked perfectly at the first attempt. So I really don't know why it doesn't work on the Ubuntu version I'm usually using. And it's just this Plot which works on the Mac OS. I have another data package which I wanted to use to make a similar diagramm, but it didn't work on Ubuntu and also not on Mac OS, so it is getting very strange.